# Echo a variable from page A on page B without include

Tags: php

I have a php script (page A) that calculates an amount payable from data it pulls from an sql database.

On that page (A) it is stored in a variable $payable.

I want to be able to show the amount payable on page B.

I cannot include page A on page B because include displays all content of page A.

I have tried with session, but with session you have to load page A for the variable to be created and be seen on page B.

What is the easiest way to display variable $payable from page A on page B without having to load page A?

Comment: send get request to page B with querystring `amount=your page A amount`

Comment: If you want the ability to show the amount on page b without first going to page a, you should separate your code a bit more. Create a separate file that contains the calculation and returns the result. Then you can include that in both page a and page b.

Answer (score 2):

This is why you should separate your code properly. Create a separate file for the calculation and include that file where you need it.

Create a new file with your calculation. Let's call it `calc.php`:

```
function calcPayable()
{
    // Do your stuff
    return 'some-result';
}
```

Now you can include this file in all the pages where you need the calculation:

Page A:

```
require 'calc.php';

$payable = calcPayable();
```

Page B:

```
require 'calc.php';

$payable = calcPayable();
```

and so on.

This is just a simplified example. Your `calc.php` file can contain functions/a class or what ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could achieve this is to dump th raw text like this
**File A**

```
If(isset($_GET['returnvariable']) && $_GET['returnvariable']=="myvar")
{
    echo($myvar);
}
```

Then access it from the other page like this
**File B**

```
$myvar_value=file_get_contents("http://www.yourdomain.com/FileA.php?returnvariable=myvar");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That won't work. Unless you include a fully qualified URL (including the url scheme, hostname and resource), PHP will try and open a local file literally called `FileA.php?returnvariable=myvar`. Even if you did include the complete URL, this would be very inefficient since it would make a full HTTP request just to get a value from another local file.